# Efficiently matching different possible substrings to the same value

Tags: java, python, regex

I have a CSV file, one column of which is called Operating System and contains a string with values that look like this:

```
win-abc123
def456-windows
123123-WIN-ghi789
rhel-jkl012
45u8234dgf-redhat-mno345
pqr678-RHEL
```

In other words, the column value contains a substring somewhere inside of the string (front, middle, or end) indicating the operating system. The values could be one of `win`,`windows`,`WIN`,`rhel`,`redhat`,`RHEL`.

I want to examine the column value, and clean it up by replacing the entire column with either `WIN` or `RHEL`.

I have a clunky solution. Iterate over each row in the CSV, and iterate over each `key, value` pair in a operating system map. If it matches, replace the CSV value.

```
os_map = {'win':'WIN', 'windows': 'WIN', 'WIN':'WIN', 'rhel': 'RHEL', 'redhat': 'RHEL', 'RHEL': 'RHEL'}
for row in rows:
    os = row[OPERATING_SYSTEM]
    for key, value in os_map.iteritems():
        if key in os:
            row[OPERATING_SYSTEM] = value
            break
```

Or, in java:

```
Map<String, String> osMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
osMap.put("win", "WIN");
osMap.put("windows", "WIN");
osMap.put("WIN", "WIN");
// Repeat for RHEL values

String os;
for (String[] row : rows) {
    os = row[OPERATING_SYSTEM];

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: osMap.entrySet()) {
        if (os.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            row[OPERATING_SYSTEM] = entry.getValue();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like this because I'm iterating through the entire map (in the worst case) before I find a match. What is a more efficient way to solve this?

If the CSV columns were simply either `win` or `windows`, without the alphanumeric characters, I could instead do this:

```
os_map = {'win,windows,WIN': 'WIN', 'rhel,redhat,RHEL': 'RHEL'}
for key, value in os_map:
    if key.contains(row[OPERATING_SYSTEM]):
        row[OPERATING_SYSTEM] = value
        break
```

But this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can do something along these lines:

```
test='''\
win-abc123
def456-windows
123123-WIN-ghi789
rhel-jkl012
45u8234dgf-redhat-mno345
pqr678-RHEL'''

from itertools import chain

os_map = {frozenset(['win', 'windows', 'WIN']):'WIN', frozenset(['rhel', 'redhat', 'RHEL',]): 'RHEL'}

all_os=set(chain(*os_map.keys()))

for line in test.splitlines():
    tgt=filter(lambda e: e in all_os,  line.split('-'))
    if tgt:
        print os_map[filter(lambda k: tgt[0] in k, os_map.keys())[0]]
```

You could also do a dict of regex:

```
import re    
os_reg={re.compile(r'\b(win|windows|WIN)\b'):'WIN', re.compile(r'\b(rhel|redhat|RHEL)\b'): 'RHEL'}        
for line in test.splitlines():
    for pat, v in os_reg.items():
        if pat.search(line):
            print line, v   
            break
```

Or combine set and regex to do something like this:

```
os_map = {frozenset(['win', 'windows', 'WIN']):'WIN', frozenset(['rhel', 'redhat', 'RHEL',]): 'RHEL'}

for k, v in os_map.items():
    test=re.sub(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(k)), v, test)

for line in test.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(os_map.values())), line)
    if m:
        print line, m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a state machine or regular expressions. Look into regular expressions in java libraries for find and replace semantics. If you are hard core you can role your own state machine which would probably be the most efficient way to handle to search part. Replace part might be a little more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) provides some nice syntaxes for this type of string replacement.  It may be very suitable if your csv file is very large:

```
In [76]:

print df

                        val
0                win-abc123
1            def456-windows
2         123123-WIN-ghi789
3               rhel-jkl012
4  45u8234dgf-redhat-mno345
5               pqr678-RHEL

In [77]:

df['val'] = df.val.str.replace(r'\b(win|windows|WIN)\b', 'WIN')

df['val'] = df.val.str.replace(r'\b(rhel|redhat|RHEL)\b', 'RHEL')

print df

                      val
0              WIN-abc123
1              def456-WIN
2       123123-WIN-ghi789
3             RHEL-jkl012
4  45u8234dgf-RHEL-mno345
5             pqr678-RHEL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with case-insensitive version of regex:

```
^.*(win(dows)?|r(hel|edhat)).*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vJ1nB9/1)

Simplified example in Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lines = {"win-abc123","def456-windows","123123-WIN-ghi789","rhel-jkl012","45u8234dgf-redhat-mno345","pqr678-RHEL"};
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^.*(win(dows)?|r(hel|edhat)).*$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("");
        for(String line : lines){
            matcher.reset(line);
            if(matcher.matches()){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```